# Moving Object3D composition

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add labels to a cube in THREE.js.

The code that adds the cubes to the scene looks like this:

```
Vertex.prototype.paint = function(scene){
  this.object = new Cube(this.options.cube);
  scene.add(this.object);
}
```

I tried modifying the code to make `this.object` a group via:

```
Vertex.prototype.paint = function(scene){
  this.object = new THREE.Object3D()
  this.object.add(new Cube(this.options.cube);
  this.object.add(new Label(this.options.label);
  scene.add(this.object);
}
```

`Cube` returns a mesh and `Label` returns a sprite. Later on in the code, I use repulsion and attraction forces to move the vertices' cubes around by calculating and setting the new positions for each vertex's mesh object but I must be missing something because with the second code, the cubes just stay in place.

How can I compose a group of objects, and manipulate them as if they were one object?

Comment: Where do these classes come from? `Vertex`, `Cube` and `Label`. Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. `Later on in the code` is not very helpful sans clairvoyance and crystal balls :)

Comment: Please share the code where you're updating the positions of your `Vertex` objects. If your cubes aren't moving, then that is likely where the problem exists.